# How to add canonical tag for all cms pages magento 2?

Tags: magento2, seo, magento-2.1.8, canonical

I want to add canonical tag for all cms pages. Currently canonical tag enabled for category and product page.

How to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Go to `Admin Panel > Content > Pages > Opne CMS Page > Design > Layout Update XML`

Add code in there

```
<head>
      <link rel="canonical" src="www.example.com/page-url-key" src_type="url"/>
</head>
```

**Update:**

To add in Catalog Search Result Page.

Add following code into `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` in

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="search_canonical" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::canonical.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Create PHTML file for canonical URL code.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/canonical.phtml

```
<link  rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'catalogsearch/result/'; ?>" />
```

Don't forget to flush the cache.

Comment: It didnt work at first but now it does. Cash has to be flushed and not refreshed.

Comment: I already mentioned Flush not Refreshed. Glad that It worked :)

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal, how to include this only on search result page?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Please check my updated code.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal, Thanks i added in default.xml inside catalog_search module. And i can see its working.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal, sure

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal Can you remove existing canonical tag on a product page? I need to remove it from specific products only and then add different canonical url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the Backend in Layout Update XML using the following snippet.

Due the fact that only referenceContainer, container, update, move elements are allowed.

```
<container name="canonical.url.container">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="canonical.url">
<arguments>
<argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com" />]]></argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</container>
<move element="canonical.url.container" destination="head.additional" before="-" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this module for the dynamic canonical link for each cms page-

https://github.com/zaxcpro/cms-canonical

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use our extension (Canonical URL extension for Magento 2 by Ecwhim):
https://www.ecwhim.com/magento-2-canonical-url-extension.html

It will help you add a canonical url to CMS pages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/206274)